# Ruby Enumerable can't compare BigDecimal NaN in min function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comparison

If I compare `a`, `b` and `c` like so

```
[a,b,c].min
```

where

```
a = BigDecimal.new("NaN")
b = BigDecimal.new("NaN")
c = BigDecimal.new("0.0")
```

I get:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of BigDecimal with BigDecimal failed
```

But if I was to use the comparison operator that ruby's Enumerable [min uses](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) then I get this:

```
irb(main):001:0>  a <=> b
=> nil

irb(main):002:0>  a <=> c
=> nil
```

And no errors are rendered. Is this an issue within Ruby or am I misunderstanding `min`, is there something else I can use to achieve the same effect as enumerable's `min` that will not explode?

Comment: the manual comparison isn't actually working, as the spaceship operator (<=>) is required to return one of `[-1,0,1]` in order to be used as a comparable. That's why you see that comparison failed, because `nil` is not a valid result. Why do you need to be able to find the min of an array including `NaN`? Can you just reject those values?

Comment: I have now just catered for any 'NaN' feedback. We get this data from an API so I can't access the data we are getting in.

Comment: Added some new information to the answer which may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Ruby language [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html):

> NaN is never considered to be the same as any other value, even NaN
>   itself:
>
> n = ::new(‘NaN’)
>
> n == 0.0 -> nil
>
> n == n -> nil

As I understand it, any instance of the `NaN` value is unique and incomparable.

Consider this code snippet:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

a = BigDecimal('NaN')
b = BigDecimal('NaN')

puts a == b
puts a > b
puts a < b
```

You'll get `false` for each of these comparisons. `min` and `max` depend sorting to produce a result, and as @phoffer pointed out, `sort` produces values of 0, 1 and -1 based on whether the second number is equal to, greater than or less than the first number.

TL;DR: Any time you're using NaN in an operation, you can't expect meaningful results.

If the API you're working with returns NaN, you can at least protect yourself against this corner case by detecting it. NaN is actually an instance of `Float`, so you can test it by using the `nan?` method.

```
2.2.0 :002 > require 'bigdecimal'
 => true 
2.2.0 :003 > a = BigDecimal('NaN')
 => #<BigDecimal:7fae1b3bd050,'NaN',9(9)> 
2.2.0 :004 > a.nan?
 => true
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That has helped me see what is actually going on. And +1 for the `.nan?` method.